# Move application extensions located in Debug folder to one folder

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-debugging

I have a WinForms application that uses 3 .dll Application Extensions. Two of them come from the KBCsv csv file parser extension, and the third is the MySQL Data extension.

Currently these files are automatically stored in the project's Debug folder along with the application itself. When I move the application to an external location, I have to keep these extensions in the same folder as the application or I get an error like:

> Could not load file or assembly 'KBCsv, Version....' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It would tidy up the desired folder that the application is to be located in if I could store these extensions in one folder, inside that folder. Any guidance as to how I could achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please  try  call Assembly.Load with the right full assembly path to load them and avoid your assembly loading issues. Reference thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29899172/9125096

Comment: @Jay, What about this issue in your side? Would you please share the latest information?

Comment: I ended up embedding the application extensions as resources in the application itself, this did the trick. I followed instructions from this YouTube video: https://youtu.be/fYgJMRLTc1A

Comment: @Jay, So it has been resolved, am I right? If so, would you please share your solution as an answer(Not a Comment) here? You could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue. Have a nice day:)